# Calculadora em C# não está funcionando

Tags: c#, .net

Criei um método que pede para o usuário digitar `numero1` e `numero2` (é um algoritmo de calculadora simples), mas esse método não armazena o que o usuário digita, independente da opção de operação que o usuário a escolha está sempre dando 0. Gostaria de como resolver este problema.

O meu código atual:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {   
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Menu();
        }
        static void Menu()
        {   int numero1 = 0, numero2 = 0;

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Escolha uma operação");
            Console.WriteLine("[1]-Soma"); 
            Console.WriteLine("[2]-Subtração");
            Console.WriteLine("[3]-Divisão");
            Console.WriteLine("[4]-Multiplicação");
            Console.WriteLine("[5]-Sair");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Selecione uma opção:");
            
            short opcao = short.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            MenuEscreva();

            string resulta = Result("O resultado é ");

            switch(opcao)
            {   
                
                case 1: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Soma(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 2: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Subtracao(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 3: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Divisao(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 4: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Multiplicacao(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 5: System.Environment.Exit(0); break;
                default: Menu(); break;
            }
        }
        static void MenuEscreva() //Menu usado para usuario digitar valores
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite um Numero:");
            int numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Digite outro Numero: "); 
            int numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        }
        static int Soma(int numero1, int numero2)
        {   
            return (numero1 + numero2);
        }
        static string Result(string result) 
        {
            return result;
        }
        static int Subtracao(int numero1, int numero2)
        {
            return (numero1 - numero2);
        }
        static int Divisao(int numero1, int numero2)
        {
            return (numero1 / numero2);
        }
        static int Multiplicacao(int numero1, int numero2)
        {
            return (numero1 * numero2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar uma variável local use um [campo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields).

Comment: Recomendo que ao formular uma pergunta, você feche um pouco o escopo da mesma. Isso vai atrair mais pessoas á respondê-las e a resposta pode alcançar mais pessoas. Por exemplo, nesse caso você poderia ter debugado um pouco seu código e ter perguntado o motivo de um método não estar retornando as variáveis instanciadas nele. Sempre é bom dar uma olhadinha no [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No método MenuEscreva() você está instanciando as variáveis *numero1* e *numero2*, que por sua vez são descartadas ao final do método. Essas variáveis só existem no escopo do método.

Quando você chama algum método de operação da calculadora (no switch case), você está passando as variáveis *numero1* e *numero2* instanciadas no começo do método *Menu()*.

Basicamente, você nunca está atribuindo valor ás variáveis instanciadas no Menu, acredito que você possa resolver isso com um novo método:

```
        static int ObterValor()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite um Número:");
            return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

dessa forma, seu método Menu() ficaria assim:

```
 static void Menu()
        {   
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Escolha uma operação");
            Console.WriteLine("[1]-Soma"); 
            Console.WriteLine("[2]-Subtração");
            Console.WriteLine("[3]-Divisão");
            Console.WriteLine("[4]-Multiplicação");
            Console.WriteLine("[5]-Sair");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Selecione uma opção:");
            
            short opcao = short.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int numero1 = ObterValor();
            int numero2 = ObterValor();

            string resulta = Result("O resultado é ");

            switch(opcao)
            {   
                
                case 1: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Soma(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 2: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Subtracao(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 3: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Divisao(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 4: Console.WriteLine(resulta + Multiplicacao(numero1, numero2)); break;
                case 5: System.Environment.Exit(0); break;
                default: Menu(); break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro da função `MenuEscreva` você está criando uma nova variável e colocando o valor que está lá dentro, porém no resto do código você está usando a variável `numero1` e `numero2` que está setada com `0`. Uma solução seria mudar a função

```
static int MenuEscreva() //Menu usado para usuario digitar valores
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite um Numero:");
    int numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return numero1;
}
```

No seu código você fará assim para prencher o `numero1` e o `numero2`:

```
int numero1 = MenuEscreva();
int numero2 = MenuEscreva();
```